# Non-Euclidean mechanics; is it useful?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, field-theory

Special relativity has the following single-particle Lagrangian:
$$S = \int_{t_0}^{t_f}\sqrt {\langle \mathrm d\vec{s},\mathrm d\vec{s}\rangle}.$$

Clearly it is based on Euclidean norms; it is in Minkowski or Riemannian-geometry norm, but both norms are only a generalization of the Euclidean norm.

Now I can formulate another Lagrangian that Looks like this:

$$S = \int_{t_0}^{t_f} ({\langle \mathrm d\vec{s},\mathrm d\vec{s},\mathrm d\vec{s}\rangle })^{\frac{1}{3}}\;.$$

I have generalized the Standard Lagrangian of a relativistic particle to the 3-norm and tried to concept a generalized scalar products for 3-norms.

Are such field theories developed now and can such field theories be constructed? Is there any evidence to construct a physical theory based on 3-norms?

Comment: What is a "3-norm"? The usual meaning of a "$p$-norm" is $\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert_p = \left(\sum_i x_i^p \right)^{1/p}$. How is  $\langle ds,ds,ds\rangle$ defined? What physical thing to you expect this to model?

Comment: Yes, a 3-norm is a p=3-norm. I don't know exactly how to define a triple scalar product; but it is a trilinear form.

Comment: Are you aware that all $p$-norms on finite-dimensional normed spaces are equivalent? And how do you think you can actually define this on a *manifold*?

Comment: @ACuriousMind will they really result in the same equations of motion when used as OP suggests?

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this is an interesting enough question, or at least non-trivial.

Comment: @Ruslan: Equivalence of norms $\lvert-\rvert_1$ and $\lvert-\rvert_2$ means that there are $c,d$ such that $c \lvert v\rvert_1\leq\lvert v\rvert_2\leq C\lvert v\rvert_1$. So extremizing one of those will also extremize the other. Additionally, it is unclear how to add the Minkowskian nature here - do you just write a minusin front of the first entry?

Comment: The title question (v2) _Is it useful?_ seems primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 6):

OP's proposal (v2) is a special case of [Finsler geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finsler_manifold) with $n=3$. The main idea is to replace the quadratic metric tensor $g^{(2)}_{\mu_1\mu_2}$ for [pseudo-Riemannian manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold), which defines (infinitesimal, possibly imaginary) distance on the manifold via

$$ds ~=~ \sqrt[2]{g^{(2)}_{\mu_1\mu_2}dx^{\mu_1}dx^{\mu_2}},$$

with (possibly a sequence of) higher metric tensors $g^{(n)}_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_n}$ with a Finsler distance formula
$$ds ~=~ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \sqrt[n]{ g^{(n)}_{\mu_1\ldots\mu_n} dx^{\mu_1}\ldots dx^{\mu_n}}.$$

There exists already a [huge literature](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=Finsler+geometry+physics) on Finsler geometry and its applications to physics.