Why does the line element expression contain only second order differential terms?
The general expression of the line element $ds^2$ is $$ds^2 = g_{ij}dX^{i}dX^{j},$$ where $g_{ij}$ is an element of the metric tensor.
Is there a rigorous proof of why there are no terms in the expression of $ds^2$ that are of higher order than $2$? Would it be possible to construct a space where this would be true (even if this space could not be used in physics)?

It’s a definition motivated by Pythagoras’ theorem (which motivated Riemannian geometry, which is then broadened to Lorentzian geometry for GR). You can definitely study all sorts of tensor fields but the fundamental object for GR is this symmetric non-degenerate $(0,2)$ tensor field.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/532206/2451 and links therein.
