# Why is the time part of the space-time with exactly second degree?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time

Why is exactly $n = 2$ in the equation
$$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\left( {ds} \right)}^n} = {{\left( {c \cdot dt} \right)}^n} - {{\left( {dr} \right)}^n}}\\
{dr = \sqrt {{{\left( {dx} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {dy} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {dz} \right)}^2}} }
\end{array}{\text{ ?}}$$
Is the light speed constancy performed at any $n$? It is known, that a good accuracy is in experiments and observations, when   $n = 2$ is used. But why $n$ is not 2.0001 or 1.9999? Were experiments or observations to measure $n$? What is the accuracy of $n$?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233539/2451

Comment: This is another question. Why the degree of the time is the same as the degree of the space? But by the link, the time is considered as an equal part of the space-time.

Comment: @Imyaf $\text{distance}^2 = x^2 +y^2 +z^2$ and $\text{distance}=ct$ by the definition of velocity $v=d/t$ where $v=c$.

Comment: it really is just the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: Pythagorean theorem is applicable only for the Euclidean space. But first, it is needed to prove that time is an equal part of the euclid space-time. Deformation from gravity is not considered in this question.

Comment: @Imyaf That is not exactly true. The Pythagorean Theorem holds in a stationary frame. so i can use it to calculate the distance a light ray travels in my stationary frame. if i have synchronized detectors set up or some such thing.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the fact that the speed of light is constant so $c^2 dt^2=dx^2 +dy^2 + dz^2$ for points on a light ray.

Comment: It  is just the Pythagorean theorem, when the time is an equal part of the space-time. But why the time is an equal part of the space-time? This is not obvious. This should be measured in experiments or observation.

Comment: @Imyaf The fundamental assumption is that the speed of light is constant. so $c^2 dt^2=dx^2 +dy^2 + dz^2 \rightarrow 0= - c^2 dt^2 +dx^2 +dy^2 + dz^2$ then the fact that this is true of all inertial observers implies the Lorentz Transformations and that $-c^2 dt^2+dx^2 +dy^2 + dz^2$ is invariant.

Comment: $$\begin{array}{l}
ds = 0\\
0 = {\left( {c \cdot dt} \right)^n} - {\left( {dr} \right)^n}\\
\frac{{{{\left( {dr} \right)}^n}}}{{{{\left( {dt} \right)}^n}}} = {c^n}\\
\frac{{dr}}{{dt}} = c
\end{array}$$

Comment: @lmyaf No, no, no and no again. $d \mathbf{r}$ is the differential of a vector quantity, and even for a light when $ds = 0$, you write it as $0 = c^2 dt^2 - |d \mathbf{r}|^2$, being $|d \mathbf{r}|$ the norm-2 of the elementary 3D displacement  vector $d \mathbf{r}$, i.e. its Euclidean length, that can be evaluated with Pythagora Theorem.

Comment: $dr=\sqrt{\left( dx \right)^2+{\left( dy \right)^2}+{\left( dz \right)^2}}$ is differential of Euclidean length of space without time.
Speed of light is invariant
$$ds = 0$$
$$0= {\left( {c \cdot dt} \right)^n} - {\left( {\sqrt {{{\left( dx \right)}^2} + {{\left( dy \right)}^2} + {{\left( {dz} \right)}^2}} } \right)^n}$$
$$\frac{{{{\left( {\sqrt {{{\left( dx \right)}^2} + {{\left( dy \right)}^2} + {{\left( dz \right)}^2}} } \right)}^n}}}{{{\left( dt \right)^n}}}=c^n$$
$${v_{\text{light}}}=\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{{\sqrt {{\left( dx \right)^2}+{\left(dy\right)^2}+{\left(dz\right)^2}}}}{dt}=c$$

Comment: @Imyaf $c^2 dt^2 = dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2 \space \rightarrow \space cdt = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2 +dz^2}$ All you've done is exponent both sides by n and then taken the nth root.

Comment: Maybe one could consider a particle at speed v<c and measure its eigentime experimentally ?

Comment: @Cretin2 what is eigentime?

Comment: Eigentime is the time in the moving frame : We would have $c^nd\tau^n=c^ndt^n-dr^n=c^ndt^n-v^ndt^n\Rightarrow d\tau=\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{v^n}{c^n}}dt$ in Imyaf question.

Comment: @Cretin2 ok. that's just empirically wrong. unless n=2.